# How to get single product receipt from app store which is recently purchase using in IAPHelper in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When I am testing auto renewal subscription in sandbox environment. I am fetching receipt from app store. It provides me receipt with multiple product id with the help of `IAPHelper` while I need only one single product receipt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Apple receipt will always contain all the product Ids the user has purchased. You can use `exclude-old-transactions` when [verifying the receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) to only get the latest subscription renewal if that's helpful.

Comment: How will i exclude old transaction?

Comment: Add the following key to the JSON object you send to the verify endpoint that includes your receipt-data `exclude-old-transactions=true`

Comment: But i am receiving receipt by IAPHelper class.so will i add this to JSON